# Does CSS :hover conflict with jquery .mousseenter?

Tags: jquery, css

Does CSS :hover conflict with jquery .mousseenter? Currently having an issue with a nav where a jquery event and css animation trigger at the same time. The css :hover event will not trigger unless I mouseover the element slowly. If it is mouse'd over too quickly it will not trigger until the next time I trigger it.

[Navigation menu to show what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j2VR.png)

Jquery makes the sub menu show. I have a mouseenter set up for both the products nav item as well as the containing div holding the sub menu.

We also have an animation on each of the submenu elements.

When you mouse for the first time from the global nav to the sub nav the animation will not trigger unless I mouseover slowly. If its fast at all it will not trigger until I move to the next element on the sub-menu element and it will then trigger fine.

Comment: no they dont maybe its either there is a bug in your code or wrong logic

Comment: post your code, so you will get the very help u need